# Cakephp - Wizard Component - echo session data from previous step in next step

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm quite new to Cakephp, I've been developing a project for the last two months that uses the [Wizard Component](https://github.com/ProLoser/CakePHP-Wizard) that helps create multi page forms.

My question is how do I set the session data to the view of the next step in the process from the previous step.

Thus far I have this in my controller

controller/Uploadstylecontroller.php

```
CakePlugin::load('Wizard');

class UploadstyleController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('Post');
        public $components = array('Wizard.Wizard');
        var $username = array();
    public function beforeFilter(){

        $this->layout = 'loggedinnorightbar';
        $this->Auth->allow('wizard','uploadstyle','styledetails','uploadcomplete');
        $this->Wizard->steps = array( 'uploadstyle','editpicture');
        $this->Wizard->wizardAction = '/uploadstyle/wizard/uploadstyle';
        $this->Wizard->completeUrl = '/uploadstyle/uploadcomplete';

        }

        public function uploadcomplete(){
        }

        public function wizard($step = null) {
        $this->Wizard->process($step);

    }
/**
 * [Wizard Process Callbacks]
 */
    public function processUploadstyle() {

        $this->Post->set($this->data);

        if($this->Post->validates()) {
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    public function processEditpicture() {
        $uploadstyle = $this->Wizard->read();
        $this->set( 'uploadstyle',$uploadstyle );
        if($this->Post->validates()) {

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

I won't bother with the saving of the data since that is working fine.

and in my view uploadstyle/editpicture.ctp

```
<div class="signupwrapper" style="position:relative; width:470px; margin-top:30px;">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Uploadstyle', array('id' => 'UploadstyleForm', 'url' => '/uploadstyle/wizard/editpicture'));


    echo $this->Form->hidden('Post.shines', array('value' =>  0));

    echo $uploadstyle['Post']['image_name'];

    ?>
    <div class="submit">
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Continue', array('div' => false)); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Cancel', array('name' => 'Cancel', 'div' => false)); ?>
    </div>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

</div>
```

In regards to the 'echo $upload['Post']['image_name']' is there something in the component that I need to activate or am I referencing the array incorrectly in the view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm sorry if this was a long question, my first time asking a question here.

Comment: I figured it out finally!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution if this might help anyone in the future in regards to using this cakephp component.

I moved the following code to the function beforeFilter() in the controller the wizard is applied to.

```
    $wizardData= $this->Wizard->read();
    $this->set( 'uploadstyle',$wizardData);
```

Then in the view.ctp all I have to do is echo the following to get my value

```
echo $uploadstyle['uploadstyle']['Post']['image_name'];
```

And Vola! I have access to my wizard session on any step of the form.

I really hope this is helpful to someone with a similar problem.